# is there a way to make a application that will complete the setup/installation page of any kind of .exe

Tags: c#, installation, exe

so the title might be a bit confusing but i will explain it.

what i am trying to make is a application that when runned it will start up a different .exe file. *for example it can be Minecraft or Visual Studio.*

that is done with command lines.

After starting it i want it to complete the setup or installation automatically. (the part where you click yes or continue to finish the installation).

if there anyone who knows how or still does not understand ask me because i cant find something like this on google.

Comment: In general you'd look at whether those installers have a "silent" option. That's what e.g. Ninite does.

Comment: For VS, there's an entire section of the documentation dedicated to performing [command-line installs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio?view=vs-2022). And that's the *sort* of thing you'd need to check on a per-product basis. And due to it's complexity, the chances you get a satisfactory installation by just clicking "Next" on each page and not selecting options to customize the install are practically zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found a answer for my question using command line.

What i did i opened a command prompt and typed "setup.exe /?".
It opened a window with a [list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91Mk5.png) of different parameters.

So when i insert "setup.exe /S /v/qn" it will install the setup silently that means it will not show you the installation page and just install it without asking you anything.

P.S. if /? does not work try -y that works for some applications.